# problem splitting a string

Tags: c++

Can some one please tell me the problem with this code. I am reading each line using `getline` function and again using the same function for splitting the string for `:` delimiter.

```
 string line,item;
 ifstream myfile("hello.txt");

 if(myfile.is_open()) {
   string delim =":";
   while(!myfile.eof()) {
     vector<string> tokens;
     getline(myfile,line);
     stringstream iss(line);

     while(getline(iss,item,delim)) {
       tokens.push_back(item);
    }
  }

  myfile.close();
}
```

The error message is:

```
C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided 1> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(528) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
```

Comment: also can someone format the code pls. I am unable to do it.

Comment: The formatter can get confused if you start with code. I moved your question in front of the code.

Comment: @mousey: Never mix tabs with spaces to indent source code. I prefer spaces (because the formatting will appear the same in virtually all editors -- and in a shell). A good IDE will have tab/space settings.

Comment: @mousey: Also, pasting the exact error message will help.

Comment: Can you also provide sample input & output for your code?

Comment: @Marcelo: The formatter requires blank lines in source code to be indented with at least four spaces, as was the case with mousey's code.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't compile. What is the actual code you tested?

Comment: @Marcelo cantos the code is not compiling. That is my problem

Comment: @Dave, his code was indented correctly, and even appeared correctly on the edit screen, but it was broken on the main page. Perhaps the tabs messed it up.

Comment: @Dave error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(528) : see declaration of 'std::getline'

Comment: @mousey: Ah! Sorry for misreading you.

Comment: @mousey: Add the error description to your question.

Comment: Also (I can't edit either) may someone please delete the `c' tag, this looks C++ specific to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `char delim = ':';` and I also suggest using `istringstream` instead of `stringstream`. Also, the loop is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
...
  char delim = ':';
  while (std::getline(myfile,line))
  {
    vector<string> tokens;
    istringstream iss(line);

    while(std::getline(iss,item,delim))
    {
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
  }
  myfile.close();
```

Also, note that `tokens` will get reset on each line. If you intend to accumulate `tokens` across lines, declare it before the outer loop.

Comment: I've amended the answer to indicate the headers you need. Do you have all those?

Comment: I am using 

    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string line,item;
    ifstream myfile("hello.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()) {
        char delim =':'; // use char instead of string as Marcelo Cantos said
        while(!myfile.eof()) {
            vector<string> tokens;
            getline(myfile,line);
            stringstream iss(line);

            while(getline(iss,item,delim)) {
                tokens.push_back(item);
            }
        }
    }

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use `oef()` as predicate in the while loop. Better would be to call `getline()` there.

Comment: @rubenvb can you please explain why I shouldnt use eof() ?

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ under the section "checking state flags": eg when a stream goes into `fail` state, a next extraction will work on the same byte sequence. Moreso, see eg http://mathbits.com/mathbits/compsci/Files/End.htm that also recommends using `getline` instead of `eof()`. When a read fails for another reason than eof reached, you miss the error. In most cases, it also allows for shorter code :). As an additional reference (although it is C, the same happens for C++ streams):http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Answer (score 0):

You read each line of the file just until the first delim occures - not the complete line. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/:

> Characters are extracted until either
>   (n - 1) characters have been extracted
>   **or the delimiting character is found**
>   (which is delim if this parameter is
>   specified, or '\n' otherwise)specified, or '\n' otherwise)

Comment: yes I am reading a line and then using that line to split it. But my code is not working. Its giving me a syntax error!

Comment: `getline(myfile,line)` in his code does read the complete line. He then stuffs it into a `stringstream`, and reads until delimiter _from that_. It's not clear which of those you're referring to (if any).

Comment: @TheJuice error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided


error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::istringstream'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(476) : see declaration of 'std::getline'

Comment: you are describing `std::istream::getline`. @mousey is using `std::getline` from `<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer to wrap std::getline with an iterator interface so that it
plays nicely with other iteration based algorithms. Here is
an easy way to do this.

```
    /** Proxy class to help the LineStreamIterator 
     * consume lines.
     */
    class LineString {
        std::string buffer;
    public:
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, LineString &li) {
            std::getline(is, li.buffer);
            return is;
        }
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const LineString &li){
            os << li.buffer;
            return os;
        }

        operator std::string () const { return buffer; }
    };

    /**  Base class of the LineIterator */
    typedef std::istream_iterator<LineString> LineIteratorBase;

    /** An input iterator that yields lines from the
     * istream it is constructed with.
     * @code
     *  LineIterator it(cin);
     *  for (; it !=LineIterator(); ++it){
     *      std::cout << *it << " --- " << std::endl;
     *  }
     * @endcode
     */
    class LineIterator : public LineIteratorBase {
    public:
        LineIterator() : LineIteratorBase()
        {}

        LineIterator(std::istream & is): LineIteratorBase(is)
        {}

        /** Implement the dereference so that a string is
         * returned
         */
        const std::string operator * (){
            return (std::string) this->LineIteratorBase::operator *(); 
        }

        /**  value_type trait */
        typedef std::string                value_type;

        /**  pointer type trait */
        typedef std::string*               pointer;

        /**  reference type trait */
        typedef std::string&               reference;

    };
```